# How to create Hot observable in reactive extension

Tags: oracle, event-handling, system.reactive, reactive-programming, oracle-aq

I am trying to use Reactive extensions with Oracle AQ. When a message comes on Oracle Queue, it fires a "OracleAQMessageAvailableEvent" which tells the consumer that there is a message. Inside the OracleAQMessageAvailableEventHandler the consumer calls OracleAQQueue.Dequeue() to retrieve the message.

I have got the above working with RX. Following is the code I have used.

```
var messages = Observable.FromEventPattern<OracleAQMessageAvailableEventHandler, OracleAQMessageAvailableEventArgs> (
                    h => _queue.MessageAvailable += h, h => _queue.MessageAvailable -= h)
                .Where(x => x.EventArgs.AvailableMessages > 0)
                .Select(x =>
                {
                    OracleAQMessage msg = _queue.Dequeue();
                    return (UpdateMsg) msg.Payload;
                });
messages.subscribe(....)
```

Problem is that if I subscribe to messages once everything works but if I subscribe to messages multiple times (i.e multiple consumers inside my application) then every consumer will try to call "_queue.Dequeue()" and every call after the first call will fail if we have no new message.

Could anyone please guide me what should I do. I think, my scenario is for Hot Observable but I am struggling to get my head around it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are correct that you are looking for a Hot Observable.
If we follow the code it may be more clear why you are seeing `_queue.Dequeue();` being called multiple times.

First you subscribe to the event from Oracle

```
Observable.FromEventPattern<OracleAQMessageAvailableEventHandler, OracleAQMessageAvailableEventArgs> (
    h => _queue.MessageAvailable += h, 
    h => _queue.MessageAvailable -= h)
```

This is just like hooking up an event handler as you would have in a pre-Rx world.
Everyone the listens (subscribes) will receive the same events. 
If they subscribe after an event is raised, then they have missed it.

Then you filter out empty sets.

```
.Where(x => x.EventArgs.AvailableMessages > 0)
```

Nothing special there.

Then you perform a side effect from inside your query.

```
.Select(x =>
    {
        OracleAQMessage msg = _queue.Dequeue();
        return (UpdateMsg) msg.Payload;
    });
```

The side effect here is that you are making a destructive read (`Dequeue`).
All subscribers when they are pushed an event from the upstream `_queue.MessageAvailable` will all try to call `Dequeue()`.

To avoid all of the subscribers to invoke the side effect, you can make the sequence Hot (as you suggested).
To do this you can look at the `Publish()` operator.

The `Publish()` operator will return you an `IConnectableObservable<T>` that just extends `IObservable<T>` by adding the `Connect()` method.
This allow fine grained control of when the subscription logic is executed.
However, this maybe too much control for you, and you will probably find that `RefCount()` to be just what you need.

```
Observable.FromEventPattern<OracleAQMessageAvailableEventHandler, OracleAQMessageAvailableEventArgs> (
    h => _queue.MessageAvailable += h, 
    h => _queue.MessageAvailable -= h)
.Where(x => x.EventArgs.AvailableMessages > 0)
.Select(x =>
    {
        OracleAQMessage msg = _queue.Dequeue();
        return (UpdateMsg) msg.Payload;
    })
.Publish()
.Refcount();
```

Now each of your subscribers will receive the same message, and your `Dequeue()` side effect will only be invoked once per event (and only while there are subscribers).

Hot and Cold observable's are covered [here](http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/14_HotAndColdObservables.html)

Comment: Thank you for your comment but it is still trying to call _queue.Dequeue from multiple subscriber. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you think, I should be using a Subject instead of Observable.FromEventPattern. Users can subscribe to the Subject which is exposed as IObservable. When the message is received from OracleAQ and the handler is fired I could dequeue the message once and call Subject.OnNext(NewMessage) which will takecare of multiple subscribers ?

Comment: Even though I think you are fine now (with your answer below), I thought I would answer - No I dont think you should use a subject. I rarely think anyone should use a subject. It generally points to a design flaw.

Answer (score -1):

Lee Campbell, Sorry my bad. The solution you mentioned does work. Actually, I was using it incorrectly. I have a class call QueueWrapper which has a property called Messages. I had this implementation of Messages

```
    public IObservable<UpdateMsg> Messages { 
        get { return Observable.FromEventPattern<OracleAQMessageAvailableEventHandler,         OracleAQMessageAvailableEventArgs> (
        h => _queue.MessageAvailable += h, 
        h => _queue.MessageAvailable -= h)
       .Where(x => x.EventArgs.AvailableMessages > 0)
       .Select(x =>
        {
            OracleAQMessage msg = _queue.Dequeue();
            return (UpdateMsg) msg.Payload;
        })
       .Publish()
       .Refcount();
}}
```

and my client code was subscribing using Messages property like this

```
// First Subscription
_queueWrapper.Messages.Subscribe(....)

// Second Subscription
_queueWrapper.Messages.Subscribe(....)
```

so for each subscription, Messages property was returning a new IObservable. To fix this, I moved the initialization of observable to the constructor of QueueWrapper i.e following code :

```
    public QueueWrapper() {
     _messages = Observable.FromEventPattern<OracleAQMessageAvailableEventHandler, OracleAQMessageAvailableEventArgs> (
        h => _queue.MessageAvailable += h, 
        h => _queue.MessageAvailable -= h)
    .Where(x => x.EventArgs.AvailableMessages > 0)
    .Select(x =>
        {
            OracleAQMessage msg = _queue.Dequeue();
            return (UpdateMsg) msg.Payload;
        })
    .Publish()
    .Refcount();
}
```

and my Messages property just return _messages;

```
public IObservable<UpdateMsg> Messages { get { return _messages; } }
```

After that everything started working as expected.